# Jooq choose when statement on multiple columns

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have this part of query:

```
case 
    when columnA = 'On' 
        and columnB <= current_date() 
        and columnC > current_date()
        then columnA
    else 'NoChange'
end)
```

is it possible to write it in Jooq, Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`CASE` expression](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/) in jOOQ almost as you would, in SQL.

```java
// Assuming this static import, as always
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

when(T.COLUMN_A.eq("On")
    .and(T.COLUMN_B.le(currentDate()))
    .and(T.COLUMN_C.gt(currentDate())), T.COLUMN_A)
.else_("NoChange")
```